# GCP pus/sub. How can I request volume of data coming through subscription in a period of time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to understand the volume of data coming to my subscription in GCP pub/sub. How can I request this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub surfaces via Stackdriver various metrics about the performance of your topics and subscriptions. See https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring. In particular, these are the Cloud Pub/Sub metrics: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub. For the volume of data coming through your subscription, the relevant metrics is `subscription/byte_cost`.

Comment: Thank you, was blind to not see this particular metric.